# OKhttp как принять картинку (file) на php сервере?

Tags: php, android, http

1)Есть официальный [пример](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/recipes/PostMultipart.java) как отослать картинку,

но нет кода как на php сервере принять эту картинку. Как будет выглядеть код для принятия этой картинки?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

В общим официальный пример "https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/recipes/PostMultipart.java" плохой: может он устарел, а ссылку на его не сменили, может я что то не понял.

Вот мое решение.

```
    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
                .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("val1", "74")
                .addFormDataPart("val2", "93435880")
                .addPart(
                        Headers.of("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"logo-square.png\""),
                        RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, new File("/storage/sdcard0/ava.jpeg")))//директория картинки на устройстве, получил её когда сохранял картинку методом folderToSave = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url[1])
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
return response.body().string();
```

PHP сервер

```
 $nameReg=$_POST['val1'];
  $nameNom=$_POST['val2'];



    f($_FILES["image"]["size"] != 0){
      //Проверка, действительно ли загруженный файл является изображением
      $imageinfo = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
      if($imageinfo["mime"] != "image/jpeg" && $imageinfo["mime"] !="image/png") {
        print_r($_FILES["image"]);
      print "<br />Загруженное фото1 не в формате jpeg или jpg ";die;
      }

      //Сохранение загруженного изображения с расширением, которое возвращает функция getimagesize()
      //Расширение изображения
      // Эти эксплоиды я бы и удалил, но может пригодится в будущем.
      $mime=explode("/",$imageinfo["mime"]);
      //Имя файла
      $namefile=explode(".",$_FILES["image"]["name"]);
      //Полный путь к директории
      $uploaddir = "./fotota/";//папка куда будет сохранено изображение


      //Функция, перемещает файл из временной, в указанную вами папку и именует изображение. $mime[1] - в данном случае .jpeg
      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $uploaddir."kartinka.".$mime[1])) {
        print "<br />Изображение1 успешно загружено.<br />Фото обновится через некоторое время.";
      }else{
        print "<br />Изображение1 Произошла ошибка";
      }
    }
```

Пользуйтесь, долго это решал.

Answer (score 1):

можете воспользоваться примером загрузки файлов из [оф.документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

Comment: Спасибо, попробую, но все же хотелось бы увидеть живой пример.

Comment: там приведён абсолютно живой пример. вам всего лишь нужно, в соответствии с написанным там же, вписать свои «реалии».

Comment: Александр, совершенно неожиданно наткнулся на этот ответ в очереди проверки сообщений низкого качества. Предлагаю вам перенести код примеров в ответ.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, тут такая штука: код как таковой абсолютно бесполезен без необходимой для понимания процесса **остальной** информации, изложенной по ссылке. к тому же: 1. информация изобилует отсылками к другим частям документации. 2. я затрудняюсь оценить *правовой* аспект копирования этой информации к нам на сайт. 3. эта страница не «уйдёт в небытие», т.к. запротоколирована, например, на [archive.org, в количестве 261 экземпляра ещё с 2009-го года](https://web.archive.org/web/20150615000000*/http://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: там лицензия CC-BY: http://php.net/manual/en/copyright.php

Comment: @NickVolynkin, внизу страницы, ссылку на которую я привёл, есть ссылка под названием [*copyright*](http://php.net/copyright.php) с несколько иным содержанием. // по моему предыдущему комментарию: я не очень чётко выразился — там **длиннющая статья**, явно не вписывающаяся в формат ответа на s.o., да ещё и изобилующая ссылками. // по-моему, ссылка на статью — это самый оптимальный вариант **в данном случае**. альтернативой ссылке было бы написание краткого конспекта изложенного по ссылке. но, честно говоря, у меня нет желания писать такой конспект.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, если считаете ответ не подходящим, скажите прямо — я удалю его без всяких тайных мыслей. или просто проголусуйте за его удаление. с моей стороны — никаких претензий быть не может.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: посмотрел статью — действительно очень длинная. Я считаю ответ подходящим, но подозревал, что можно сделать его еще лучше. Нет возможности улучшить — пусть будет такой. Ссылка на официальную документацию это куда надежнее, чем какой-нибудь торрент или блог.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, сделать лучше — всегда возможно. а чтобы облегчить возможным желающим этот процесс — я сделал ответ общим.

Answer (score 0):

@alexander barakin Вам предоставил оф.документацию по работе с файлами на **PHP**.
На сервер файлы приходят в глобальном массиве `$_FILES`, если Вы выполните команду `var_dump($_FILES)`, то Вы сможете увидеть файл\файлы которые отправляете.

где будет примерно следующее

```
Array
(
    [file1] => Array
        (
            [name]// название Вашего файла
            [type] //тип файла
            [tmp_name] //временый файл
            [error] //статус загрузки
            [size]// размер в байтах
        )
```

Comment: Logcat выдает просто слово Array. Response response = client.newCall(request).execute(); return response.body().string();

Comment: Вы массив выводите строкой.  `но нет кода как на **php сервере** принять эту картинку. `
Если используете php сервер используйте его средства

Comment: Так Вы не увидите пустой массив или нет

Comment: var_dump($_FILES) в logcat  выводит array(0) значит файл сервер не видит.

Comment: нет! значит файл не был отправлен на сервер